# How to delete elements on a list from the en until a condition become true in python?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, package, delete-row

I have data about projet per month and it appear that there is a lot of 0 at the end of each project because the project is kept alive in the system for a while after the project is finish.

What I want to do is to delete for a given project all the rows, starting from the last one and descending, who have the following condition true. The condition will be in this case the column 'PRODUCTION' equal to 0.

I would like to know if there is a package to do that fast, because the last time i tried to do a loop on my data it took forever. Or any efficient solution using pandas.

edit: I have solved my problem by using a loop after a group by, it took not too much time.

Comment: Please provide us some sample data and expected output.

Comment: Your title says you want to delete list elements, but the question says you want to delete dataframe rows. Please clarify.